# WebRTC PeerConnection showing black screen on Safari 11 (Mac OS X 10.13)

Tags: javascript, macos, safari, webrtc

I'm using WebRTC to stream video (without audio) from a webcam on a Raspberry Pi to the user's browser. On the RPi, I've installed [kclyu/rpi-webrtc-streamer](https://github.com/kclyu/rpi-webrtc-streamer), and I've copied over some of the test code for the browser client from that repo as well.

On my Mac OS X 10.13 desktop, the client code displays video just fine on Chrome 63 and Firefox 58, but on Safari 11, all I get [a black screen (albeit of the correct size)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcHgy.png). Though Safari support seems to be pretty recent in WebRTC, what I've read suggests that it should at least be able to support an RTCPeerConnection with H.264 codec in this version of Safari. Any ideas on what might be going wrong?

Here's an excerpt of our JavaScript (it's not the best, but hopefully it's understandable with just the parts here):

```js
var pcConfig = {"iceServers": [{"urls": "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"}]};
var pcOptions = {optional: [{DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement: true}]};

this.createPeerConnection = function() {
    var that = this;
    this.peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(pcConfig, pcOptions);
    this.peerConnection.onicecandidate = function(event) {
        if (event.candidate) {
            var candidate = {
                type: 'candidate',
                label: event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
                id: event.candidate.sdpMid,
                candidate: event.candidate.candidate
            };
            // send(data) sends the data over the established WebSocket connection
            send(JSON.stringify(candidate));
        }
    };
    this.peerConnection.onconnecting = onSessionConnecting.bind(this);
    this.peerConnection.onopen = onSessionOpened.bind(this);
    this.peerConnection.onaddstream = onRemoteStreamAdded.bind(this);
    this.peerConnection.onremovestream = onRemoteStreamRemoved.bind(this);
}

function onRemoteStreamAdded(event) {
    this.videoEl.srcObject = event.stream;
}

// the rest of the callbacks only log, and do nothing else
// includes onSessionConnecting, onSessionOpened, onRemoteStreamRemoved

this.doHandlePeerMessage = function(data) {
    ++this.messageCounter;
    var dataJson = JSON.parse(data);
    if (dataJson["type"] == "offer") {
        var that = this;
        var data = '';
        var sdp_returned = forceChosenVideoCodec(dataJson.sdp, 'H264/90000');
        dataJson.sdp = sdp_returned;
        this.createPeerConnection();
        this.peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(
            new RTCSessionDescription(dataJson),
            onRemoteSdpSuccess,
            onRemoteSdpError
        );
        this.peerConnection.createAnswer({iceRestart: false}).then(function(sessionDescription) {
            data = JSON.stringify(sessionDescription);
            return that.peerConnection.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
        }).then(function() {
            // again, send(data) sends the data over the established WebSocket connection
            send(data);
        }).catch(function(error) {
            // log error
        });
    } else if (dataJson["type"] == "candidate") {
        var candidate = new RTCIceCandidate({sdpMLineIndex: dataJson.label, candidate: dataJson.candidate});
        this.peerConnection.addIceCandidate(candidate, aic_success_cb, aic_failure_cb);
    }
}

// again, the callbacks only log, and do nothing else
// includes aic_success_cb, aic_failure_cb, onRemoteSdpSuccess, onRemoteSdpError
```

(I'm pretty new to WebRTC, so if there's anything obviously wrong, please let me know!)

Comment: Could you fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is caused by not adding `playsinline` into your html video element.

So it has to be something like this:

```
<video id="local-video" playsinline autoplay muted></video>
<video id="remote-video" playsinline autoplay></video>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue, and the suggested props to the video element didn't help. What did resolve this for me was adding a button for Safari users that calls the `play` method on the video element:

`<button onclick="document.getElementById('webcam').play()">Play</button>`

If you try to call the `play` method from the console or programmatically, you'll get:

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotAllowedError (DOM Exception 35): The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission

Answer (score -1):

you need to add some props to the video tag

```
<video playsinline controls autoplay/>
```